# The Nativescript 6.0 implementation of angular/common/http seems to have broken HttpHeaders. Is there a solution?

Tags: angular, http, nativescript

I have an app I have been developing with Nativescript Angular.  Recently, an update to Nativescript 6.0 was required.  Following the update the code to create HttpHeaders for http.get with new HttpHeaders appears to be broken.
A console out of the following code (which worked previously):

```
        let mycustomheaders = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + appSettings.getString("token")
        });
        console.log("createRequestHeaderheaders: " + JSON.stringify(mycustomheaders));
```

produces:

```
        createRequestHeaderheaders: {"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null}
```

The example code for this which i used and worked previously is here:
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ng-framework-modules/http#http

Any insight and help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when `JSON.stringify` would have done what you expect there, but the Angular version you're using likely requires that you access it via `keys` and `get` (or `getAll`).

```js
console.log("createRequestHeaderheaders: " + JSON.stringify(
  mycustomheaders.keys().map(
    (key: string) => `${key}: ${mycustomheaders.get(key)}`,
  ),
));
```

Comment: Thanks Ian.  Still have an issue that arose from this Nativescript update, but seeing the headers displayed eliminates that as the problem and gets me one step closer.